# Bloomberg R Error (Missing Value where True/False)

Tags: r, bloomberg

**I am relatively new to using Bloomberg in R. The last part of my code looks to cycle through all the tickers in the FTSE100 and check if each company market cap is greater than 1bn:**

It throws up the error "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

How do I get past this issue?

```
#######################################################################################
#install all packages and apply library
#######################################################################################
#install.packages("openxlsx")
library("openxlsx")
#install.packages("devtools")
library("devtools")
#install.packages("Rblpapi")
library("Rblpapi")
#install.packages("zoo")
library(zoo)
#install.packages("TTR")
library(TTR)
#install.packages("lubridate")
library("lubridate")
#install.packages("quantmod")
library("quantmod")
#install.packages("MASS")
library("MASS")
#install.packages("dplyr")
library("dplyr")
#install.packages("ggplot2")
library("ggplot2")

con <- blpConnect()
c <- 4800
b <- Sys.Date()-4
a <- b-c

###########################################################################################
# # performance periods.
###########################################################################################
onemonth <- b-(30)
threemonth <- b-(90)
sixmonth <- b-(180)
oneyear <- b-(365)

###########################################################################################
# # benchmark to retrieve members. For example this would be NMX and one below would be UKX
###########################################################################################
benchmark1 <- "ukx index"

###########################################################################################
# # benchmark to calculate returns. 
###########################################################################################
benchmark2 <- "ukx index"




#################################################################################################################
# # THIS IS THE CODE TO match time series to one data frame and one time series. 
#################################################################################################################
###########################################################################################
# # Initialise bbg code, drop the tickers into the bbg loop.. 
###########################################################################################



###########################################################################################
# # market one month return 
###########################################################################################
con <- blpConnect()

p1 <- bdh(benchmark2, 
          fields = c("PX_LAST"), 
          start.date = onemonth, end.date = b)
p1$date <- as.Date(p1$date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
p1$PX_LAST <- as.numeric(p1$PX_LAST)

mktonemonthrtn <- (last(p1$PX_LAST))/(p1$PX_LAST[1])-1



###########################################################################################
# # market three month return 
###########################################################################################
con <- blpConnect()

p2 <- bdh(benchmark2, 
          fields = c("PX_LAST"), 
          start.date = threemonth, end.date = b)
p2$date <- as.Date(p2$date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
p2$PX_LAST <- as.numeric(p2$PX_LAST)

mktthreemonthrtn <- last(p2$PX_LAST)/(p2$PX_LAST[1])-1



###########################################################################################
# # market six month return 
###########################################################################################
con <- blpConnect()

p3 <- bdh(benchmark2, 
          fields = c("PX_LAST"), 
          start.date = sixmonth, end.date = b)
p3$date <- as.Date(p3$date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
p3$PX_LAST <- as.numeric(p3$PX_LAST)

mktsixmonthrtn <- last(p3$PX_LAST)/(p3$PX_LAST[1])-1



###########################################################################################
# # market one year return 
###########################################################################################
con <- blpConnect()

p4 <- bdh(benchmark2, 
          fields = c("PX_LAST"), 
          start.date = oneyear, end.date = b)
p4$date <- as.Date(p4$date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
p4$PX_LAST <- as.numeric(p4$PX_LAST)

mktoneyearrtn <- last(p4$PX_LAST)/(p4$PX_LAST[1])-1






#########################################################################################################################
# # PULL IN ALL TICKERS FROM THE BROADMARKET INDEX.
#########################################################################################################################
p <- bds(benchmark1, "indx_mweight_hist", overrides = c(end_date_override="20170428"))
p$tickers <- paste(p$`Index Member`, " EQUITY")
p <- cbind(p[3], p[2])

tickers <- p[1]



#########################################################################################################################
# # CHECK THEIR LENGTH AND WHETHER IT IS VALID. CREATE FILTERED TICKERS.
#########################################################################################################################
filteredtickers <- rep(0, nrow(tickers))

con <- blpConnect()


for (i in 1:nrow(tickers)){
  q <- bdh(tickers[i,], 
           fields = c("CUR_MKT_CAP"), 
           start.date = a, end.date = b)
  q$date <- as.Date(q$date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
  q$CUR_MKT_CAP <- as.numeric(q$CUR_MKT_CAP)
  #class(q) == "data.frame"
  qlength <- (last(q$CUR_MKT_CAP))/1000

  if (qlength > 1){
    print(tickers[i,])

    if(qlength > 1){
      filteredtickers[i] <-  tickers[i,]}

  }

}

t <- as.data.frame(filteredtickers, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
t <- subset(t, filteredtickers!="0")
colnames(t) <- "tickers"
```

Comment: where specifically (which line) throws the error?

Comment: for (i in 1:nrow(tickers)){
  q <- bdh(tickers[i,], 
           fields = c("CUR_MKT_CAP"), 
           start.date = a, end.date = b)
  q$date <- as.Date(q$date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
  q$CUR_MKT_CAP <- as.numeric(q$CUR_MKT_CAP)
  #class(q) == "data.frame"
  qlength <- (last(q$CUR_MKT_CAP))/1000

  if (qlength > 1){
    print(tickers[i,])

    if(qlength > 1){
      filteredtickers[i] <-  tickers[i,]}

  }

Comment: When I hit a particular stock called Scottish Mortgage Investment Trust, for (i in 1:nrow(tickers)){
  q <- bdh(tickers[i,], 
           fields = c("CUR_MKT_CAP"), 
           start.date = a, end.date = b)
  q$date <- as.Date(q$date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
  q$CUR_MKT_CAP <- as.numeric(q$CUR_MKT_CAP)
  #class(q) == "data.frame"
  qlength <- (last(q$CUR_MKT_CAP))/1000

  if (qlength > 1){
    print(tickers[i,])

    if(qlength > 1){
      filteredtickers[i] <-  tickers[i,]}

  }

Comment: I'd be willing to bet that the Scottish Mortgage Investment row has some missing data then (I'm guessing in `CUR_MKT_CAP`).

Comment: correct. Given that its an investment trust, technically this is not a stock so market cap does not appear properly as usually this is called NAV for a trust. Is there any way to skip this error?

Comment: Yes, use a try().  See http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Exceptions-Debugging.html for details.

Answer (score 0):

The `missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed` error typically happens when R is doing some kind of logical operation but is missing the data it needs.  I'm guessing the culprit is the `if (qlength > 1)`, since `qlength` is calculated from `q$CUR_MKT_CAP`, and from your comments, that doesn't exist in this row of data.

So the solution really depends on what you need to do.  The easiest thing to do if appropriate is to remove this row (or similar rows) from the input dataset with

```
tickers1 <- tickers[-i,]   # where i is the offending row number
```

or

```
tickers1 <- tickers[!is.na(tickers$CUR_MKT_CAP),]  # if this field is NA
```

And then use `tickers1` instead of `tickers` from here on out (or else overwrite `tickers` instead).

The other alternative is to build something else into the loop, with either a `try()` (thanks PhilC) or a logical check that will specifically catch what throws the error, something like

```
for (i in 1:nrow(tickers)){
  q <- bdh(tickers[i,], 
           fields = c("CUR_MKT_CAP"), 
           start.date = a, end.date = b)
  if(!is.na(q$CUR_MKT_CAP)) {   # possible error check?
    q$date <- as.Date(q$date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
    q$CUR_MKT_CAP <- as.numeric(q$CUR_MKT_CAP)
    #class(q) == "data.frame"
    qlength <- (last(q$CUR_MKT_CAP))/1000
    if (qlength > 1){
      print(tickers[i,])
      if(qlength > 1){
        filteredtickers[i] <-  tickers[i,]}
      }
    }
  }
  # else {
  # ... operations to do instead? ...
  # }
}
```

Hope this helps --

Answer (score 0):

You would really be better off using the EQS function on Bloomberg, and linking to a saved search with the BEQS function. This was introduced into Rblpapi some time ago and the helpdesk will be able to help you set up the initial screen. Once you have something saved, you can retrieve it as follows.

If you had a custom saved EQS screen called "Swedish Mid Caps", all you need is the screen name and to set screenType flag to 'PRIVATE'. :

```
sw_eqs <- beqs(screenName = "Swedish Mid Caps", screenType = "PRIVATE")
```

Comment: Dear Morgan, thank you for your advice. Both suggestions have been great. I am glad you brought up the issue of EQS. I have spoken to A desk several times including our bbg rep and all have told me that I am unable to receive assistance with regards to R. Would you suggest getting in touch with them once again?